# Node.js - How to Convert Buffer to file or blob

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-storage, multer

The problem is. I want to upload a file or image from my Node.js express project to Firebase Storage. I'm using multer to parse the image files. But then i face a problem

I tried to print the object file and then this is the output :

```js
{ fieldname: 'field_name',
  originalname: '1.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 08 06 06 07 06 05 08 07 07 07 09 09 08 0a 0c 15 0e 0c 0b 0b 0c 19 12 13 0f ... >,
  size: 75469 }
```

Okay, that's the file object. the only thing that i think i can process is the buffer. But, the firebase storage said that it only accepts a 'file' or 'blob'. Then i tried to find out how to convert that Buffer to a file or blob. Until now, i cant find the way to do it. Please help me.

Comment: Convert your image to a base64 encoded string and store that

Comment: okay i will try

Answer (score 0):

By default - multer save the uploaded file to your server filesystem.

So you can read the file from there and upload it by google SDK like this [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs).

Don't use the client side library of Firebase for your server side code.

Comment: mmm. but to use the google cloud storage. even for free, i need to input a credit card. i dont have it yet. but i really need the service. why i cant use the firebase storage instead?

Comment: See the note here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files. It's the same storage, but firebase sdk main purpose is for uploading from browser.